# Arch linux net configuration Operation: No Such file or Directoy

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi

I ma currently in the middle of installing arch linux on my old lenovo g560. This is my second attempt at installing arch-linux. My problems are when I am trying to enable the wireless service with `systemctl enable net-auto-wireless.service`. But when I run it all I get is:

```
Operation failed: No Such file or Directory.
```

How would I fix this problem?

Comment: You get that error because there is no systemd service called `net-auto-wireless.service`. What are you trying to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Wiki's Wireless page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless)
..

You must have network from somewhere Ethernet I suppose
 as [@HalosGhost mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161642/arch-linux-net-configuration-operation-no-such-file-or-directoy#comment264599_161642), when in doubt read the wiki.

You must be precise with `systemd` anyways and all CLI.

If you have problems we need specifics and logs. Arch is very hands-on but you can do it if you try and want to.

The documentation is there.